# Can anyone explain this program? We cannot start a thread twice but we are getting an output 1-20.. can anyone explain?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test implements Runnable {
    private int m, n;

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                m++;
                n++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(m + ", " + n);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Test a = new Test();
            new Thread(a).start();
            new Thread(a).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect? And what you are getting instead?

Comment: Please, explain what you need

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that you cannot start the *same* thread twice. But you aren't doing that here. You are starting two **separate** threads once each.

Your code is essentially the same as:

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(a);
        t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring 2 different threads and running them one after another. If you add the following code.

```
public synchronized void run() {
System.out.println("thread started");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m++;
            n++;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(m + ", " + n);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("thread fininshed");
}
```

You can easily see where the first thread ends and then the second thread starts.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your threads needs to execute task described in instance of `Test` class. More precisely in its `run` method. In your case both threads will need to execute task of `Test` but they will also need to use same instance of this class (which is stored in `a` reference).

Problem is that `run` method is *synchronized* which means it uses monitor/lock of current instance (`this` - available via `a` reference) which means that both threads can't execute it *at the same time*. To be more precise one of threads will need to wait until other thread will finish execution code from that synchronized block (which is entire body of `run`).

So in your case

- one of your threads will print

  - enter synchronized block locked on `a`
  - print values in range 1-10
  - exit synchronized block locked on `a`
- so now another thread can

  - enter synchronized block locked on `a`
  - print values in range 11-20 (since `m` and `n` will be increased each time in loop)
  - exit synchronized block locked on `a`